# KooBoo experiences and cases

Tags: sharepoint, content-management-system, intranet, kooboo

I´m considering using Kooboo as an intranet management system. Are there same featured in Kooboo that are present in SharePoint?

Where I can find examples of Kooboo extensions' development? I haven't found any extension showcase as Umbraco has. Is there something alike?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One year ago, we launched a website powered by Kooboo CMS.
The deployment was easy and everything was OK. The problem is that a lot of modules are not set or not mature enough to be used under the production environment.

For example, there was a big bug in the forum module. As we couldn't wait future releases that would come with the fixes, we considered editing the code.

On the other hand, the admin interface is really awesome: Full AJAX and easy to understand.

But, unhopefully, I would not recommand this CMS as it is still IMO in a development process.

Answer (score 0):

Kooboo is a good open source CMS, but IMO it's not possible to compare it with Sharepoint. Kooboo is not an enterprise level CMS.

You can found examples on the [Kooboo forum](http://forum.kooboo.com)